# Select image from popup and display in main page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, dropzone.js

I am using bootstreap3 popup(model) to select image from computer.
I want when user select one or more image then popup should be closed and image uploading preview should be display in main page (below the `<i class="fa fa-image image-popup-open" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".photo-modal-lg"></i>`).

My code is

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <div class="controls form-inline">
            <i class="fa fa-image image-popup-open" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".photo-modal-lg"></i>
            <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h4>Upload Images</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="modal-title">
                                </div>

                            <div id='content' class="tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane active" id="uplod">
                                    <h1>Drag and Drop files using Dropzone.js</h1>
                                    <form action="upload.php"
                                          class="dropzone"
                                          id="my-awesome-dropzone"></form>
                                </div>

                            </div>    
 </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

My code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xrcwrn/d2r4r16p/) .
How to do this

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("imageid").src="../template/save.png";
```

Comment: it would have been better if you add some explanation too.